# DDD - CreatedBy/CreatedOn in the Domain Model?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, dto

When writing an application by standard for each table in the database I have the following properties: `CreatedOn`, `CreatedBy`, `ModifiedOn`, `ModifiedBy`, `Archived`.

But trying to follow DDD I'm questioning whether these properties are truly part of the domain and should be included within the domain objects. If i were to exclude these "metadata" properties from the domain but still wanted them in my database then I'd need to implement some kind of DTO layer if I was going to use a ORM.

So the domain model is mapped to a DTO, the `CreatedOn`, `ModifiedOn`, etc is set and then pushed to the database.

So I suppose my questions are:

1. Do I just live with these properties as part of my domain model?
2. Do I remove them but have the headache of having to map DTO's?
3. Is there an alternative that would elimate both problems like implementing some form of audit log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing Domain-Driven Design, your entities usually won't have much to do with the structure of the database.

You'll quickly come to a point, where you need to map between the ORM's table-objects and your domain's aggregates anyway.

Forcing database-driven aspects into your domain model contradicts what DDD is all about.

So yes, I'd recommend mapping the ORM's table-objects (which are pure data anyway) into your aggregates. This is where the Repository pattern comes into play. It will provide the domain's objects by transforming the underlying data.

If meta-data like creation/modification date and user are not inherently part of the business domain (i.e. a system-wide logging requirement) the given user and date/time can be injected when transforming back into table-objects to save.

An layered architecture might look like the following:

```
 ----------------------------
| Domain                     | (Aggregates)
 ----------------------------

 ----------------------------
| Repositories               | (transforms table-objects into Aggregates)
 ----------------------------

 ----------------------------
| OR-Mapper                  | (loads records from DB into table-objects)
 ----------------------------

 ----------------------------
| Database                   | (this is where the data lives)
 ----------------------------
```

Comment: So in other words in a large scale system that will possibly need to be optimised at some stage a DTO layer will be unnavoidable?

Comment: @David exactly. I extended my answer a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to find that out is by asking your product owner if those fields are relevant in your model. And if they are, which enteties are they relevant on?

---

> If i were to exclude these "metadata" properties from the domain but still wanted them in my database then I'd [.....]

Why? They are not part of the model, which menans that they are not part of any logic in your domain.

> 3.Is there an alternative that would elimate both problems like implementing some form of audit log?

If an audit log is an requirement then they should be part of the model.

Comment: Well in a data heavy system for example a CRM or ERP there is a generally a requirement to track who's done what and when. If you consider a "Customer" domain entity with all the properties and functionality you might imagine, is who the customer was created by or modified by part of the domain? I suppose from what you are saying if it's a business requirement for that information to exist then it probably is part of the domain.

Comment: CRM is not a very good fit for domain driven design imho. DDD excels at modeling complex business domains, and not for building generic systems like a CRM. You could however borrow things from DDD like persistance ignorance.

Comment: @jgauffin CRM. when implemented properly as a task oriented tool, is a very good candidate for DDD. What we've come to understand as CRM is quite often not such, as they are often purely CRUD-systems, in which DDD is not a good fit. But even in a mainly CRUDdy CRM, there are portions, or bounded contexts, where DDD may well be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers that state that the 'metadata' is not *necessarily* part of the domain.

If your domain is an Identity and Access Control domain then you are going to have user names and the like involved.  For anything using the Identity and Access BC things may be different.  You may need to add some user information into your domain in the form of a value object.

For the most part I feel this data belongs an the application service level.  It may be an option to have some context object populated by the application service that your repository has access to in order to populate the relevant DB fields.  In this way it stays out of your model.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a separate domain like "DomainHistory" with those specific columns.

Something like:

```
UserHistory or UserMeta

`Id`
`CreatedOn`
`CreatedBy`
`ModifiedOn`
`ModifiedBy`
`Archived`
```

This domain's responsibility is to populate those specific columns in your table based on the Id you provide.

Not sure if this is what others meant when they mentioned mapping DTOs here. But doing it this way could provide a middle-ground to what you're trying to achieve.